# Getting Flink cluster configuration at runtime

Tags: apache-flink

I'm interested in getting at runtime the number of TaskManagers and slots of a Flink cluster, before submitting jobs to it (I'd like to tune some program parameters based on the cluster ones).

Does anybody know which functions should I call to get these parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are available through Flink's REST API.

Full API documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/monitoring/rest_api.html

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to get them through the standard Java API? (I couldn't find them via the `StreamExecutionEnvironment` class)

Comment: @cesco well the job itself is not aware of what is happening in the cluster. If you want to access the data from Java, you can make an HTTP call to the REST API from within your Flink job (before you call `execute`).